# Xamarin Launcher.OpenAsync PDF FileUriExposedException

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm a total Xamarin N00b.
I am trying to open a local PDF but I am missing some kind of permission or something, I really don't know what to search for / what to ask, as I am a beginner Xamarin.Forms user.

Here is the issue:
[image]

Comment: please do NOT post code as an image

Comment: Whole code is "Launcher.OpenAsync(filePath)"... the other info from the image is important. THANKS.

Comment: "file://" is a URI, not a path

Comment: Thanks, Jason, now it works in the Emulator. It doesn't work on my device, though. Maybe because I have multiple apps for opening PDFs and it doesn't know which one to chose? Is there any way to make it work with Launcher.OpenAsync?

Comment: Jason, I see you are a Xamarin MVP. Can you, please, provide an example on how to open a local PDF? Thanks!

Comment: Where did you put the pdf? Is still in your application folder, or other external storage? Here is a blog about it, you can refer to it.https://xamarinstudy.blogspot.com/2019/07/how-to-open-image-and-pdf-from-local.html

Comment: If you have mutiple apps for opening PDFs, you can choose the browser to open it